# Where is income sourced if I work for an agency in one state that provides my services in another?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I'm a self-employed contractor.  I live in NY, "work" for a NY agency that provides my services to a company in CT.  Do i have to claim that income as CT sourced, or NY sourced?

Comment: Who actually pays you?  Are you paid by the NY agency, or by the company you provide services to?